# What's the equivalent of .gitignore in unity teams?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

Title says it all. I want unity to not sync a directory with the rest of the team due to the 1gb restriction on personal accounts - is there any way to do that?

Comment: There is no difference in the way you use gitignore in Unity and other type of project. Git is not understanding the type of project you are using. So look for how to ignore a folder/file in git and you have your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a documentation page describing what you seek.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCollaborateIgnoreFiles.html

To answer the Question:
**.collabignore is the equivalent file**

Quote from the Documentation above.

> To add your own exclude rules to the .collabignore file:
>
> 1. Read the GitIgnore documentation on Git-SCM.com.
> 2. Edit the .collabignore file to add your new rules.
> 3. Start the Unity Editor (or restart the Editor if it is already
>      running).
> 4. Publish your .collabignore file changes in Collaborate to share your
>      exclusions with the rest of your team.

Comment: in case the link dies, *.collabignore* is the equivalent file

Answer (score 1):

yes, put the name of that directory as a separate line in your .gitignore file.